# rsync not working with variable containing a white space

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I cant get my rsync script to work if source or destination variable have a space in the folder name

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST="root@192.168.1.100"
source="/path/My Files/"
dest="/path/My Files2/"

rsync -avhP --delete "$HOST":"$source" "$dest"
```

the error i get is

```
receiving incremental file list
rsync: [sender] link_stat "/path/My" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/root/Files" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Any help how to write this would be great

Comment: You can also simply escape the space, e.g. `source="/path/My\ Files/"` and `dest="/path/My\ Files2/"` (though you have to know you need to escape in advance, or have a shell tool do it for you). The `--protect-args` in @Cyrus answer is pretty nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add option `-s` with current `rsync` version.

From `man rsync`:

> **-s**, **--protect-args**: This  option sends all filenames and most options to the remote rsync without allowing the remote shell to interpret them.  This means that spaces are not split
> in names, and any non-wildcard special characters are not translated (such as ~, $, ;, &, etc.).  Wildcards are expanded on the remote host by rsync (instead of
> the shell doing it).

Comment: I've probably read though every `rsync` option over the past 20 years, but hadn't paid close attention to `-s`. That's handy and eliminates the need to escape.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Cyrus and  David C. Rankin